Why does MatcherBase class in gtest-matchers.h define a VTable, and what is its purpose?
Why does MatcherBase class in gtest-matchers.h from googletest define a VTable, and what is its purpose? I speculate that it implements a mechanism similar to a virtual function table, but why not just use virtual functions directly?
The VTable is defined at line316 in the below link:
https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/1d17ea141d2c11b8917d2c7d029f1c4e2b9769b2/googletest/include/gtest/gtest-matchers.h#L316
I tried to search and ask some LLMs, but I didn't get good answers. I'd like to get professional answers from C++ experts. Thank you!

The question should be complete and contain an embedded code you talk about, the link can be an addition to the code.

You could look at the change history.

Change Matcher to allow binding an implementation by value directly:

Drop the requirement of MatcherInterface. Doing manual type erasure avoid
extra layers in many cases.
Avoid the adaptor for MatcherInterface<T> and MatcherInterface<const T&> mismatch.
Use a small object optimization when possible. This makes things like
_ and Eq(1) really cheap and do not require memory allocations.


Matchers usually do not have data members and are small objects. They wanted to pass these small (empty) objects by values instead allocating them dynamically and pass pointers or references (polymorphically). The solution was dropping the requirement of implementing MatcherInterface<T> and as an extra bonus it helped to avoid extra adapters to matchers. Compare the old one and the new any matcher:
template <typename T>
class AnyMatcherImpl : public MatcherInterface<const T&> {
 public:
  bool MatchAndExplain(const T& /* x */,
                       MatchResultListener* /* listener */) const override {
    return true;
  }
  void DescribeTo(::std::ostream* os) const override { *os << "is anything"; }
  void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const override {
    *os << "never matches";
  }
};

class AnythingMatcher {
 public:
  template <typename T>
  operator Matcher<T>() const { return A<T>(); }
};

const internal::AnythingMatcher _ = {};
// Creates a matcher that matches any value of the given type T.
template <typename T>
inline Matcher<T> A() {
  return Matcher<T>(new internal::AnyMatcherImpl<T>());
}

template <typename T>
inline Matcher<T> An() { return A<T>(); }

vs.
class AnythingMatcher {
 public:
  using is_gtest_matcher = void;

  template <typename T>
  bool MatchAndExplain(const T& /* x */, std::ostream* /* listener */) const {
    return true;
  }
  void DescribeTo(std::ostream* os) const { *os << "is anything"; }
  void DescribeNegationTo(::std::ostream* os) const {
    *os << "never matches";
  }
};

const internal::AnythingMatcher _ = {};
// Creates a matcher that matches any value of the given type T.
template <typename T>
inline Matcher<T> A() {
  return _;
}

template <typename T>
inline Matcher<T> An() {
  return _;
}

It results in dropping the extra level like AnyMatcherImpl, adapter to const T& mismatch, and small object value optimizations instead of dynamic allocations.

The VTable class is indeed used to implement dynamic dispatch, something that regular virtual tables do. The code is essentially something like this:
template <typename T>
class MatcherBase{
 public:
  bool MatchAndExplain(const T& x, MatchResultListener* listener) const {
    return vtable_->match_and_explain(*this, x, listener);
  }
  template <typename P>
  static auto MatchAndExplainImpl(const MatcherBase& m, const T& value,
                                  MatchResultListener* listener)
      -> decltype(P::Get(m).MatchAndExplain(value, listener->stream())) {
    return P::Get(m).MatchAndExplain(value, listener->stream());
  }
protected:
  template <typename U>
  explicit MatcherBase(const MatcherInterface<U>* impl)
      : vtable_(nullptr), buffer_() {
    Init(impl);
  }
  template <typename M, typename = typename std::remove_reference<
                            M>::type::is_gtest_matcher>
  MatcherBase(M&& m) : vtable_(nullptr), buffer_() {  // NOLINT
    Init(std::forward<M>(m));
  }
private:
  struct VTable {
    bool (*match_and_explain)(const MatcherBase&, const T&,
                              MatchResultListener*);
  };
  template <typename P>
  const VTable* GetVTable() {
    static constexpr VTable kVTable = {&MatchAndExplainImpl<P>};
    return &kVTable;
  }
  template <typename M>
  struct ValuePolicy {
    static const M& Get(const MatcherBase& m) {
      // When inlined along with Init, need to be explicit to avoid violating
      // strict aliasing rules.
      const M* ptr =
          static_cast<const M*>(static_cast<const void*>(&m.buffer_));
      return *ptr;
    }
  };
  // Other ValuePolicy class templates... 
  template <typename M>
  void Init(M&& m) {
    using MM = typename std::decay<M>::type;
    using Policy = ValuePolicy<MM>;
    vtable_ = GetVTable<Policy>();
    Policy::Init(*this, std::forward<M>(m));
  }
  const VTable* vtable_;
  Buffer buffer_;
};

From above, we can see MatcherBase<T>::MatchAndExplain() calls the corresponding MatcherBase<T>::MatchAndExplainImpl<P>(), where P is a ValuePolicy class whose type is determined from the constructor. This is known as the policy-based pattern. The ValuePolicy determines how to interpret MatcherBase<T>::buffer_ as a matcher via ValuePolicy::Get(), which can be a MatcherInterface<U> in case of the constructor listed above (note that U is not necessarily the same as T), or some other class with a MatchAndExplain function implemented. In particular, that class (typically a user defined matcher) does not need to inherit from the MatcherInterface<U> class, it only needs to implement the corresponding functions. An example custom matcher given in the gmock documentation looks like this,
note that it does not inherit from anything.
class BarPlusBazEqMatcher {
 public:
  using is_gtest_matcher = void;
  //...

  bool MatchAndExplain(const Foo& foo,
                       std::ostream* /* listener */) const {
    return (foo.bar() + foo.baz()) == expected_sum_;
  }
  //...
 private:
  const int expected_sum_;
};

In general, when classes have a common interface (e.g. with specific functions implemented) but do not share a common parent, you cannot use the virtual function system provided by the language and have to roll your own dynamic dispatch mechanism. Note that you also cannot make the ValuePolicy template classes inherit from a common ValuePolicyBase because the ValuePolicy::Get() functions don't share a common return type.

If anyone spots anything factually wrong in the answer, please leave a comment so that I can improve it.

This looks like an AI generated answer which is banned on SO.

@3CxEZiVlQ I didn't use GenAI at all when composing this answer. I am well aware of the policy and the recent incident of a high-rep user. Thank you anyway for letting me understand that the downvote may be related to suspected use of genAI.
